# Consume a web service using WSE3.0 or WCF?

Tags: wcf, web, webclient, wcf-security, wse3.0

I have to use a number of functions provided by a government web service.  I have no idea what they used to implement this service.  Could have been COBOL for all I know.
My problem is that I've been trying to access this service using the security features provided by WSE3.0 but have had no luck.  I'm consistently getting errors regarding the certificates.
After some research I've realized that WSE3.0 is essentially defunct and I should be using WCF.  But, I'm only writing a client and most literature seems to refer to the services themselves.
Is there even such a thing as using 'WCF' to write a client?  Should it matter which I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, WCF is a great choice for writing a web service client. Here is [how to create the client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) ("add service reference"). After this you need to create the binding (just like in the service samples).

Comment: Ya, upon further reading I do see a lot being said about client apps themselves using WCF.  Might as well go that way as it seems to be the preferred method these days.